# Prestashop 1.7 - display module without hook

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Can i display module (for example - language switcher) inside template directly, without hook?

I seem to have problem with custom hook, every i add (using `theme.yml` of current theme) wont output anything inside template.

I know these hooks are added to database, they appear in "position" site in admin panel (only when i select "Display non-positionable hooks"), but wont output any module in frontend (i add them into template of course - like this `{hook h='coolkid'}`).

Answer (score 0):

If your module implements the WidgetInterface then you can call the module directly without using a hook.

In the template instead of

```
{hook h='coolkid'}
```

You'd call it using

```
{widget name='coolkid'}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/widgets/).